# Angular checkbox is not refreshed but the behaviour occures

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I created an Angular app.
In my app I have a checkbox. By checking the checkbox I add or remove shapes.

```
<div class="checkboxAndLabel">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{shape.id}}" name="checkbox"
       ng-model="shape.isSelected" ng-click="controller.addOrRemoveShape(shape)"/>
    <label for="{{shape.id}}"></label>
</div>
```

The function:

```
myApp.controller('Controller', [ function(){
   this.addOrRemoveShape = function(shape){
        if (shape){
            var isSelected = shape.isSelected;
            if (isSelected === true){
                //ADD SHAPE
            }
            else{
                //REMOVE SHAPE
             }
     }
     ....
```

This function works perfect. If I put a breakpoint - when I will click on the checkbox I will go to this function.

In another place I added a button.
When a user clicks on the button some shapes have to be added and of course the checkboxes have to be checked.

```
this.showOrHidePredefinedShapes = function (layer){
    var shapes = layer.shapes;
    for (var i .... shapes.length){
       var shape = shapes[i];

       shape.isSelected = true;
       that.addOrRemoveShape(shape);
    }
}
```

It is working. The shapes are drawn and the checkboxes are checked. However, when I click on the checkbox for the specific selected shapes in order to uncheck them the shape is removing but I can't enter into the breakpoint and the checkbox is still stayed checked. 
I don't understand why....

Comment: It would be really helful if you could create a fiddle/plunker demo.

Comment: Probably it's not the cause, but I guess this 'ng-model="stage.isSelected"' has to have shape.isSelected instead of stage.isSelected, no?..

Comment: It's really shape in the reality. My mistake when I copied it to here. Still the problem exists

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to offer somewhat different approach:
`ng-repeat` all shapes on layer and add `ng-if` on shapes by their `isSelected` property.

```
<div class="layer">
    <div class="shapes" ng-repeat="layer.shapes">
        <div class="shape" ng-if="shape.isSelected">
            <!-- render the shape -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```